# How to get Object Oriented Programming Concepts?

Tags: java, class, object, object-oriented-analysis

I want to ask what is the best way or best resources or tutorials to learn Object Oriented Programming. I suppose most answers will be practice but for example I begin a program with java and all my codes goes just one class I can't estimate when I need to create a new class and operate on these class together. Thank you for your answers. Have a good day.

Comment: Maybe for `programmers.stackexchange.com` ?

Comment: Read books about object oriented design, practice what's in the books, repeat.  As a general starting point, when you write a program think about real-world objects which would interact as part of that logic.  For example, if you're writing something where customers can purchase items, you might have objects such as Customer, Product, PurchaseOrder, etc.  Each one has its own attributes and its own responsibilities.

Comment: Read, study, ask and question.  Look at open source projects, ask and question what concepts they have employed and why.  ps- I like the question, but it's not well suited for SO

Answer (score 1):

In order to clearly understand the object orientation, take your “hand” as an example.

The “hand” is a class. Your body has two objects of type hand, named left hand and right hand. Their main functions are controlled/managed by a set of electrical signals sent through your shoulders (through an interface).

So the shoulder is an interface which your body uses to interact with your hands. The hand is a well architected class. The hand is being re-used to create the left hand and the right hand by slightly changing the properties of it.

Answer (score 0):

when I was studying Java programming at university we were using [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/) for programming environment. Its alot more simplistic than other IDEs, but it provides a good overview of classes and objects. As such, its a good first IDE when learning OOP.